# Keep a macro linked to an icon in the ribbon when a Word document is opened on a new computer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to know if it’s possible to create a macro that will assign a button/icon in the ribbon to a specific macro for the first time the word document is open on a new computer.

My problem is that I have worked on macros on a word document and for this document I have assigned a macro “Macro1” to a button that I have placed in my ribbon for easier access. This Macro1 opened a user form which I want to be completed by the user of the document. I don’t want it to simply open the user form when a user opens the word document, this is why I need a button to show the user form if the user form needs to be closed for a moment when a user is on the word document. I have saved the macros in this specific word document with the button linked to the user form but when I opened it on a new computer, I clicked OK on the ribbon to activate the macro, but my button linked to the Macro1 was no longer there.

I need to send this document to colleagues, but they do not perform by their knowledge of Word (so do I with VBA) so I need this easy access button to open the user form.  How can I do if I don’t want them to manually link the macro to a button/icon and to put it in the ribbon?

Comment: You need to research ribbonx as you will need to add ribbon customization to the document. There is a CustomUI editor available, but you will need to write the xml yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For Ribbon customizations that travel with the file, you must edit the XML with a utility like [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor). There are lots of web pages to assist you with learning how to do this.

For a simpler solution, add the command to the **Quick Access Toolbar** instead. Set the *Customize Quick Access Toolbar* dropdown to **For Document** (where Document is the name of the file holding the macro). Then the QAT button will appear on any computer that opens the document.

Comment: "add the command to the Quick Access Toolbar instead. Set the Customize Quick Access Toolbar dropdown to For Document" That's exactly what I needed. Thank you :) !